# Memory allocation in Caesar cipher

Tags: comparative-review, go, caesar-cipher

```
// Rotate replaces the letter with that one the provided places down the alphabet.
// Ignores non-ASCII letters.
func Rotate(c Byte, shift int) byte {
    // Ignore non-ASCII letters
    if c < 'A' || c > 'Z' && c < 'a' || c > 'z' {
        return c
    }

    // Violates DRY in favor of no memory allocations.
    if c > 'Z' {
        // Lower case
        c += byte(shift)
        if c > 'z' {
            c -= letterCount
        } else if c < 'a' {
            c += letterCount
        }
    } else {
        // Upper case
        c += byte(shift)
        if c > 'Z' {
            c -= letterCount
        } else if c < 'A' {
            c += letterCount
        }
    }
    return c
}
```

Violates the DRY-principle multiple times, but does not allocate new memory.

```
// Rotate replaces the letter with that one the provided places down the alphabet.
// Ignores non-ASCII letters.
func Rotate(c byte, shift int) byte {
    // Ignore non-ASCII letters
    if c < 'A' || c > 'Z' && c < 'a' || c > 'z' {
        return c
    }

    isUpper := c < 'a'
    c += byte(shift)
    if (isUpper && c > 'Z') || c > 'z' {
        c -= letterCount
    } else if c < 'A' || (!isUpper && c < 'a') {
        c += letterCount
    }
    return c
}
```

Both caesar cipher implementation do exactly the same.
Allocates `isUpper`, but is by far more readable.

How expensive is the allocation and which implementation should I prefer?

Comment: To be eligible for code review, you must provide working (compilable) code. Type `Cipher` is missing from your code: error `undefined: Cipher`.

Comment: To be eligible for code review, you must provide working (compilable) code. You have compile errors  : `undefined: letterCount`.

Comment: @peterSO There is no requirement that the code be complete and compilable; excerpts are acceptable for Code Review. That said, sufficient context to make the question clear should be provided.

Comment: @200_success: [If your question contains broken code…](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3650/13970). The answer to this question requires  non-broken, compilable code. I've listed the absolute minimal (only two) necessary items.

Comment: It's not necessary for the question to post the ``Cipher`` code. It now should compile.

Comment: @R3turnz: `undefined: Byte` and `undefined: letterCount`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much of your code is repetitious, and you aren't checking your parameters for range.

```
func Rotate(c Byte, shift int) byte {
```

What's the difference between `Byte` and `byte`, and why are you converting?

```
    // Ignore non-ASCII letters
```

They're all potentially ASCII. I think you mean "non-alphabetic".

```
    if c < 'A' || c > 'Z' && c < 'a' || c > 'z' {
        return c
    }
```

This works, but isn't necessary. Get rid of it.

```
    // Violates DRY in favor of no memory allocations.
```

This comment provides no value.

```
    if c > 'Z' {
        // Lower case
```

After deleting the big "is-alphabetic" test above, convert this to:

```
    if 'a' <= c && c <= 'z' {
```

Which makes it clear that this is a lower-case block, and eliminates the extra tests.

```
        c += byte(shift)
        if c > 'z' {
            c -= letterCount
        } else if c < 'a' {
            c += letterCount
        }
```

I don't know what `letterCount` is. I'm guessing it's 26, but that's a guess. Also, what if `shift` is, say, 100? You haven't imposed any range on it, other than the conversion to `byte`. Let's replace the conditional stuff with an expression:

```
        c = (c - 'a' + shift) % 26 + 'a'
```

This figures out the letter-index (0..25), adjusts it for shift, wraps it around, and then puts it back in the ASCII lowercase range. **Note:** this is *probably* what you want, because "Caesar". But if you want wrapping from upper to lower case, that's a different expression.

```
    } else {
        // Upper case
```

Since we got rid of the explicit check at the top, let's convert the `else` to an `else if` and handle upper-case only:

```
    } else if 'A' <= c && c <= 'Z' {
```

Then the rest of this:

```
        c += byte(shift)
        if c > 'Z' {
            c -= letterCount
        } else if c < 'A' {
            c += letterCount
        }
    }
```

can be adjusted the same way we did the lower-case branch.

```
    return c
}
```

This return stays, and handles non-alphabetic as well as alphabetic characters.

Also, what's the difference between `Byte` and `byte`, and why are you converting from one to the other?